# iam learning and try to print in console those function but always tell me Uncaught Reference Error: object is not defined

Tags: javascript, html, css, oop, ecmascript-6

iam trying to creat object but it said object undefined in console

```
let nUser = new object();

// properties
nUser.firstName = "marwan";
nUser.lastName = "elsayed";
nUser["age"] = 37;

// methods
nUser.getTheFullName = function() {
  return `Full Name Is ${nUser.firstName} ${nUser.lastName}`;
};

console.log(nUser);
```

Comment: So many answers for a typo. A tool like eslint would probably pick up on the error. And you probably want to look into a [class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes) instead of an object.

Comment: [Working with objects - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects)

Comment: thanks it worked iam new to this so try to learn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Object must be with capital letter.

```js
let nUser = new Object();

// properties
nUser.firstName = "marwan";
nUser.lastName = "elsayed";
nUser["age"] = 37;

// methods
nUser.getTheFullName = function() {
  return `Full Name Is ${nUser.firstName} ${nUser.lastName}`;
};

console.log(nUser);
```

Answer (score 0):

Because it's `Object` - not `object`. But actually you should use `{}` instead of constructor call.

```js
let nUser = {
  firstName: "marwan",
  lastName: "elsayed",
  age: 37,
  
  getTheFullName() {
    return `Full Name Is ${nUser.firstName} ${nUser.lastName}`;
  }
}

console.log(nUser)
```

```js
let nUser = {}

// properties
nUser.firstName = "marwan";
nUser.lastName = "elsayed";
nUser["age"] = 37;

// methods
nUser.getTheFullName = function() {
  return `Full Name Is ${nUser.firstName} ${nUser.lastName}`;
};

console.log(nUser)
```